# The name 'DefaultAuthenticationTypes' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, applicationmanager

I'm trying to implement role-based authorization in my web application like following:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Login")]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string userName = model.Username;
        string[] userRoles = (string[])Session["UserRoles"];

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userName));

        userRoles.ToList().ForEach((role) => identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);

        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Login",model);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error on two lines:

```
1.ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

And:

```
2.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
```

The error 1:

```
the name 'DefaultAuthenticationTypes' does not exist in the current context
```

And error 2 is:

```
Authentication manager does not contains definition for SignIn
```

I was trying to find a solution how to implement this but I couldn't find anything related to the errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DefaultAuthenticationTypes` is part of Identity framework and found in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` namespace.

To use it, add a `using` to the top of the file

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
//...other code
identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

or call it directly

```
identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

The second issue was already dealt with in another one of your questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40306752/5233410)

Answer (score 2):

For the first, it is just a constant string

If you do not want to install packages the quickest ( and not very orthodox ) solution is

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity("ApplicationCookie");
```

you can see definition [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/DefaultAuthenticationTypes.cs)