# AuthenticationManager.SignIn() isn't present in AuthenticationManager class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm trying to use the method from the `AuthenticationManager` class `SignIn()`;

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
```

But it says that `SignIn` doesn't exists there...

The path to the `AuthenticationManager` is:

```
System.Net.AuthenticationManager
```

Am I missing something here???

Edit: Here is the mini version of the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;
using WebApplication2.ViewModels;

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Login")]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string userName = (string)Session["UserName"];
        string[] userRoles = (string[])Session["UserRoles"];

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userName));

        userRoles.ToList().ForEach((role) => identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Login",model);
    }
}
```

Edit: new error arised:

```
The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.
```

Comment: Anyone you guys ? :/ I've been trying to find out where this AuthenticationManager class is for hours, no luck so far...

Comment: [System.Net.AuthenticationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.authenticationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have a SignIn method. Are you using OWIN? check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.iauthenticationmanager.signin(v=vs.113).aspx#M:Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager.SignIn(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity[])

Comment: @Nkosi yes I'm using OWIN, I have it referenced in my application... But for some reason it's not able to call the SignIn method...

Comment: Looks like your example code is refering to the wrong type. You are going to have to show more code. show a [mcve] of the controller you are calling that code from

Comment: @Nkosi I have updated my question with all of the namespaces I'm using, alongside with the complete code for login action in the controller

Comment: Where are you using AuthenticationManager? Update doesn't show it

Comment: Edited again, my apologies ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126913/discussion-between-user987-and-nkosi).

Comment: is there an `AuthenticationManager` property on the controller?

Comment: Yes but  it only refers to the System.Net.AuthenticationManager .... It doesn't shows the one from the OWIN library for some reason :/

Comment: Show where you declare the property

Comment: I haven't declared it anywhere yet.... The documentation says I only call the static method from the class named: "SignIn" And pass it the identity parameter, which is what I've done essentially ...

Comment: It is not a static method

Comment: @Nkosi I have another problem now, I've referenced everything properly but I'm getting an error that I'm missing something in Startup class... I've created a fresh empty MVC project without the startup class. I've edited my  question, can you look into it ?

Comment: That's a new question. and also a repeated one on SO. check SO and you will see the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplified example of controller using `IAuthenticationManager`

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Web;    
//...other usings

public class AccountController : Controller {

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Login")]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            string userName = (string)Session["UserName"];
            string[] userRoles = (string[])Session["UserRoles"];

            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userName));

            userRoles.ToList().ForEach((role) => identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));

            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        } else {
            return View("Login",model);
        }
    }

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager {
        get {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the right thing, but now I'm getting error: "HttpContextBase" does not contains a method "GetOwinContext"...

Comment: Are you sure you have Owin referenced in the project

Comment: Yeah you have a good point, I missed to install a few Owin  packages from nuget... :) It works now, thanks !! :)

Comment: Specifically, it's contained in the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` package.