# Not redirect to Authorize Action Result after successful login in Identity MVC

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I am trying create a login page that should redirect to an action result on successful login. I have user roles that should check. For now I can validate user but it does not redirect to Authorize Action result. Besides it provide return url to login page. Here is my Code for **Account Controller**

```
public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        if (new UserManager().IsValid(UserName, Password))
        {
            string userName = "Test Name"; //Hard coded for test purpose
            string[] userRoles = {"Admin"};//Hard coded for test purpose

            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userName));

            userRoles.ToList().ForEach((role) => identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));

            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home"); // auth succeed 
            // auth succeed 
        }
        // invalid username or password
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "invalid username or password");
        return View();

    }

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }
```

And **Home controller**

```
[Authorize]     
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(); //Which contain Dashboard for admin panel  
    }
```

But problem is when it appear to `return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");`it not redirect but URL change to `../Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fHome`.
This is very new to me (Past I restrict user from database), Is there anything wrong with this code? Thanks in advance....

Comment: *it not redirect* - What does it do?

Comment: @NightOwl888 When it reached to 'return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");' It not  redirect  to Home controller/Action (test by debugger) rather than its Return Url to login page

Comment: That indicates that your authentication isn't working or isn't properly registered with MVC. Your code looks a lot like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40306141). Did you read the comments about missing OWIN NuGet packages?

Comment: Yes that answer I modified. I install all the packages from nuget but still same problem. It's only redirect when I use `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` with `[Authorize]` on Home/Index. But this redirect cause an error says **The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.**     @NightOwl888

Comment: add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to your form to sort out the Request Validation Token issue

Comment: I think there is some problem with my identity authorization. Do I have add something to webconfig or startup.cs (Based from some search)? @TomJohn

Comment: @Parvez was this ever solved? We ran into a similar issue this week and have no idea why RedirectToAction forces us back to Account/Login.