# DefaultAuthenticationTypes does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, using

I've tried to install the package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
and adding

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
```

in my code but I still have the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The name 'DefaultAuthenticationTypes' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304516/the-name-defaultauthenticationtypes-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: I've installed Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, it works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install package **[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/)**